# SQL Server: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: windows, .net, sql-server-2014

When I try to connect to the SQL Server I get the following error:
`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.`

The server is: `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU13) (KB4019099) - 12.0.4522.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2017 17:36:31   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`

I am an app developer, not a system nor network expert so please bear with me if description of my issue is vague or simplistic.

I am working in a corporate environment and this error is specific to only a certain users of my application. Server is on-premise and is local to my business unit. All users belongs to the same domain, are governed by the central IT and have the same system configuration, but only overseas users can't connect. When overseas users connect using central Windows Virtual Desktop there is no problem. Other users (from my local business unit) are connecting just fine.

What I have tested from my code (this is a desktop .Net Core app if that matters):

- Both `System.Data.SqlClient` and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` are throwing the same error
- `tc = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("myServerName", 1433)` connects just fine
- connection string: `Server={myServerName};Connection Timeout=60;Database={myDbName};Persist Security Info=False;User Id={user};Password={pass};` (I tried replacing myServerName with {ip},{port} but the results are the same)
- I tested connection to test and prod servers (I'm not sure whether they are different machines but their hostnames resolve to different IP addresses) but the results are the same

I can rule out Database problem of type deadlocks or heavy load etc. Also network speed or quality should not be an issue. Increasing timeouts from the connection string is not changing anything. Please help me out with what I should be asking from the admin guys. Or maybe there is something else I could try from my end?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was firewall issue - blocking users from certain geographic locations.